# How many times can a monk use opportunist per round?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk, reactions

The wording of the monk's Opportunist ability is confusing me slightly. It says :

> **Whenever** a creature within 5 feet of you is hit by an attack made by a creature other than you, you can **use your reaction** to make a melee attack against that creature.

It uses a reaction, so it should only be possible once per round but it also says you can do it **whenever** the trigger occurs  which suggests you can do it multiple times. Which is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## You only have one Reaction

The **whenever** is the trigger, but the effect is the use of your Reaction and therefore still under all of the same rules for reactions (PHB, 190).

> When you take a reaction, you can’t take another one until the start of your next turn.